# PrimeNG - Tree DragDrop, nodes are not draggable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-tree

I am following [this example](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/tree/dragdrop) from the official PrimeNG website to implement a very basic `DragDrop Tree` (I only need the re-ordering functionality, **all nodes are leaves** without children). The tree (**which is constructed dynamically**) is constructed successfully, but the nodes shown **are not draggable**, so I cannot move them up or down. Photo below

[image: The dragdrop tree created, but items are not draggable]

Code Below:

**.html file**

```
 <p-tree [value]="getItemsInTreeForm()" [draggableNodes]="true" [droppableNodes]="true"
        draggableScope="self" droppableScope="self">

 </p-tree>
```

**.ts file**

```
public getItemsInTreeForm(): TreeNode[] {
 
  let items = [{
  label: "Item1",
  data: "Backup Folder",
  expandedIcon: "pi pi-folder-open",
  collapsedIcon: "pi pi-folder"
},
  {
    label: "Item2",
    data: "Backup Folder2",
    expandedIcon: "pi pi-folder-open",
    collapsedIcon: "pi pi-folder"
  },
  {
    label: "Item3",
    data: "Backup Folder3",
    expandedIcon: "pi pi-folder-open",
    collapsedIcon: "pi pi-folder"
  }
]
return items as TreeNode[];
}
```

**NOTE:** I have tried [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67812165/why-is-drag-and-drop-not-working-in-this-primeng-tree) but in vain as nothing changed, the console of the browser does not indicate any error too.

**PrimeNG version - 12.1.0**, **Angular version - 12.2.3**, **Node version - 14.17.0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Provide the TreeDragDropService

You need to provide the `TreeDragDropService`

For example:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [TreeDragDropService], // Without it, it does not work (drag & drop)
})
```

## Initialize a property that will be manipulated by the tree

You need to have a proper variable to support your tree (not just your function return)

Initialize a property of your component with the result of the `getItemsInTreeForm()` then pass it to the template.

See in the documentation that they are not passing directly the result of `getFiles()` but taking an intermediate variable to support the tree:
`this.nodeService.getFiles().then(files => this.files1 = files);`

## My StackBlitz

Here the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tuq57d?file=src/app/app.module.ts) to the working Drag & Drop Tree on PrimeNG 12 with your data and method `getItemsInTreeForm()`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, sorry for my omission to mention that I have included the `TreeDragDropService`, so that is not a problem, but I will have a look at your example to see if I have missed something else..

Comment: For me then it is your template, you pass directly the getItemsInTreeForm(). I tried your way and had the same result than you. Try with an intermediate variable

Comment: That is correct, when I replace the function with a variable that includes the items it works fine, I guess this has to do with the workflow PrimeNG follows beneath the tree functionality, thank you :)